# attempting to assign alias to path of an exe file in dos shell

Tags: bash, shell, alias, dos

I want to set an alias to my installation of firefox so I can easily start a web page, the problem is that I dont want the script to be system dependent.
Namely I want it to be able to run on a linux distribution where the command to start firefox is already mapped to 'firefox' and can easily be run that way through bash, but on my windows machine I cant seem to get it to assign to the same variable.

I saw that I could set it to '%firefox%' via the set command but that's not quite what I want.

I believe creating aliases is possible on a windows environment because the version of svn that I use auto-installed and was able to assign itself to 'svn'. Anyone know what was involved in them being able to get their alias working, or a similar way to alias a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include your Firefox path in the %PATH% environment variable, you can start FF with "firefox". Under Windows, you should edit the system-wide settings (see [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)).

AFAIK, there is nothing similar to aliases under DOS/Windows (except the %firefox% way you mentioned, too). The 'svn' command you talked about most likely is the same thing, a 'svn.exe' and its path included to %PATH%.

This is a bit restrictive, as you can only use the original filename to launch a program, but you can work around this by creating a batch file in the program's path that launches the program, f.e. a FF.BAT that contains "firefox %1".

Alternatively, you can place a batch file in a path that already is in %PATH%, f.e. the Windows directory. That way, you don't have to modify %PATH%.